# Transaction state in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

Is there a way to know if a transaction is in an "ongoing" state in JDBC? I found nothing in the [Connection API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html).

Thanks

Comment: how would you define "ongoing state"?

Comment: I meant something like "dirty" - update, insert and delete rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDBC does not track the transaction state.  It is the job of DB to track the transaction state.

Given that, you still have two ways on tracking/knowing the transaction states.

You can make a sql call to your db to ask for transaction specific detail.  for oracle, it will be in v$transaction table in suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM v$transaction t, v$session s, v$mystat 
  WHERE t.ses_addr = s.saddr AND s.sid = m.sid AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Another solution is to use transaction manager code in some common frameworks, such as hibernate (I believe Spring has it too).

```
public interface Session {
  public abstract org.hibernate.Transaction getTransaction();
}

public Transaction {
  public abstract boolean wasRolledBack() throws org.hibernate.HibernateException;

  public abstract boolean wasCommitted() throws org.hibernate.HibernateException;

  public abstract boolean isActive() throws org.hibernate.HibernateException;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the oracle tip, it will help me.