# How to check for pending operations in a PostgreSQL transaction

Tags: postgresql, transactions, sqlalchemy

I have a session (SQLAlchemy) on PostgreSQL, with an active uncommitted transaction. I have just passed the session to some call tree that may or may not have issued SQL `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements, through `sqlalchemy.orm` or directly through the underlying connection.

Is there a way to check whether there are any pending data-modifying statements in this transaction? I.e. whether commit would be a no-op or not, and whether rollback would discard something or not?

I've seen people point out `v$transaction` in Oracle for the same thing (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending)). I'm looking for something similar to use on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Start by checking into system view pg_locks.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/view-pg-locks.html

Comment: Concluding that PostgreSQL simply doesn't have this (an equivalent of Oracle's v$transaction), I'm accepting your answer as the sensible thing to do instead.

Comment: Unless a transaction has acquired any locks, there is nothing useful to be found in pg_locks.

Answer (score 9):

Consider the following sequence of statements:

```
select txid_current();

begin;

select txid_current();
```

If the transaction id returned by the two selects is equal, then there is an open transaction. If not then there wasn't, (but now is).

If the numbers are different, then as a side effect you will just have opened a transaction, which you will probably want to close.

**UPDATE**: In fact, as @r2evans points out (thanks for the insight!), you don't need the "begin" -- txid_current() will return the same number just if you are in a transaction.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need the `begin`: if you two two consecutive queries of `select txid_current();`, if they return the same number than you are currently in a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

[Since Postgres 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-info.html):

```
select txid_current_if_assigned();
```

will return null if there is no current transaction.

If a Start Transaction has been issued, it will still return `null` if there have been no updates.

Answer (score 0):

No, not from the database level, really. Perhaps you can add some tracing at the sqlalchemy level to track it?

Also, how do you define a no-op? What if you updated a value to the same value it had before, is that a no-op or not? From the databases perspective, if it had one, it would not be a no-op. But from the application perspective, it probably would.

Comment: A redundant write would be a “no-op” too, sure, but I don't want detection of that (more cost than value). I just want to know whether the transaction has any write/delete operations, ineffectual or not.