# Determine if a transaction is active (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

How can I determine if a transaction is active? I'd like to be able to execute SQL that creates a savepoint regardless of whether or not a transaction is currently active (i.e. if it isn't active, I want to "BEGIN")

Comment: BEGIN is the keyword.

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
begin;
savepoint foo;
```

The "begin;" will be a no-op if there is a transaction already.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28802471/435563

Comment: It's a no-op, but you get a warning message

Comment: Yes -- in fact the warning message itself gives you the information you need to answer your question.