# PostgreSQL - how to determine whether a transaction is active?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql

Let me open by saying: yes, I am aware of [Determine if a transaction is active (Postgres)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485866/determine-if-a-transaction-is-active-postgres)

Unfortunately the sole answer to that question is far too specific to the use case provided, and doesn't actually indicate whether or not a transaction is active.

The `select txid_current();` trick suggested by [How to check for pending operations in a PostgreSQL transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651219/how-to-check-for-pending-operations-in-a-postgresql-transaction#28802471) doesn't appear to work - I *always* get the same transaction ID from adjacent calls to that function. Possibly this is because I'm trying to test it from pgAdmin, which is transparently starting transactions...? (Note: I don't actually care whether there are any pending changes or active locks, so looking at `pg_locks` isn't helpful - what if nothing's been touched since the transaction was started?)

So: **How can I determine in PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL code if a transaction is currently active?**

One *possible* use case is: the SP/FN in question will be doing its own explicit transaction management, and calling it with a transaction already active will greatly interfere with that. I want to raise an error so that the coding mistake of calling this SP/FN in a transaction can be corrected.

There are other use cases, though.

Ideally what I'm looking for is an equivalent to MSSQL's `@@TRANCOUNT` (though I don't really care *how deeply* the transactions may be nested...)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a clean way to do that, but you can always call BEGIN and if it succeeds it means there is no transaction in progress (don't forget to rollback). If it fails with "there is already a transaction in progress" this means you are within transaction (better not to rollback then).

Answer (score 0):

Postgres runs `PL/pgSQL` inside the transaction. Thus you can't control transaction from inside `PL/pgSQL`. Code will look like:

```
begin;
  select plpgsql_fn();
  do '/*same any plpgsql*/';
end;
```

So answering your question:

If you have `PL/pgSQL` running ATM, you have your transaction active ATM...

Of course you can do some trick, like starting/ending work over `dblink` or such. but then you can check `select txid_current();` over the `dblink` successfully...

Comment: OK, so the reason I'm seeing txid_current() always returning the same value is that I'm doing my testing from within pgAdmin rather than (supposedly) my client code which may not start an explicit transaction?

Comment: you see same, because for not modifying data statements the virtual tx_id is used, so if yu just select your tx_id you get the same number. over and over

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine if there have been any data modifications in your transaction, call `txid_current_if_assigned()`. It returns NULL if nothing has been modified yet.

If you only want to know if you are inside some transaction, you can save yourself the trouble, because you *always* are.

Before PostgreSQL v11, you cannot use transaction control statements in a function.