# oracle how to know transaction committed?

Tags: oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle: How to find out if there is a transaction pending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending)

In the Oracle, if I issue a UPDATE command in SQL PLUS, how can I know if it is committed or not ?

For example, codes below, how can I know these 25 rows are committed or not ?

```
update countries set name = 'ddd'
25 rows updated
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

use the commit statement after commit 
e.g update countries set name = 'ddd';
    commit;
and after that perform a SELECT statement to see if you have persisted to the database

Comment: A select within the same session will show you the same results regardless of whether you have committed.