# Best method to check whether Oracle connection has an associated local transaction

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle11g, transactions, odp.net

So I've got some code that updates a set of database tables via Oracle ODP.NET. The updates need to be atomic and thus need to run in a transaction. But the code can be called in two distinct scenarios: one will have already started a transaction (which I need to share), and one will not (thus I need to start my own).

My problem is, I see no easy way to check if the Oracle connection has started a transaction or not. Possible solutions (none of which I'm particularly happy with):

1. Try to create new transaction and catch exception if one has already started

   ```
   Try
       tx = OracleConnection.BeginTransaction
   Catch ex As Exception
       'do something
   End Try
   ```

*Problem: Its bad practise using exceptions for normal program flow control*

2. Check the V$TRANSACTION or similar table e.g., [[Oracle: How to find out if there is a transaction pending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending][1])

*Problem: Oracle user requires access to system tables.*

3. There's a private member on the Oracle connection object i.e., `m_oraTransaction`, that I could probably retrieve via reflection.

*Problem: Its private for a reason.*

Is there a better way?

NB. I see in Oracle12c there's a `LogicalTransactionId` property on the Oracle connection. I think this is probably a sign that Oracle spotted a deficiency and added this property.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle physically creates transaction (and the record in V$TRANSACTION) when a DML statement updates at least one row.

Using V$TRANSACTION is not ideal because you need extra privilege to access this view.

The simplest check I know is `SELECT DBMS_TRANSACTION.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID FROM DUAL`. If it returns NOT NULL value a physical transaction has been created (or you're already in existing transaction that started before).

I've never seen any other value than null in `OracleConnection.LogicalTransactionId`.

Comment: Thanks. This looked like a good answer initially but `DBMS_TRANSACTION.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID` seems to sometimes return a value when there is no transaction started on the Oracle connection i.e., `m_oraTransaction` is nothing.

I need to investigate more but it looks like there's multiple transactions running simultaneously on the same connection (I didn't think this was even possible? - I obviously need to do some reading).

Comment: This might be related to connection pooling. Because until the connections are not open at the same time one database session is shared and it could be tricky when using transactions.


Do you use `OracleConnection.BeginTransaction` or `TransactionScope` for transaction handling? Do you use multiple connection objects using the same connection string at the same time? Then Oracle can create a global transaction (I don't mean distributed!) that is shared between them.


Also if you use `TransactionScope` and control the connection status manually watch the order of the operations.

Comment: No connection pooling. `OracleConnection.BeginTransaction` and a single connection object.

It looks like an earlier `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` call is creating its own transaction but it doesn't get attached to the Oracle connection object and so I can still call  `OracleConnection.BeginTransaction` without error. Hmm....

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Transactions.TransactionScope?

```
public void Senario1()
{
  using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
  {
    //your odp.net op here:
    //var cmd = new OracleCommand();

    //also do senario2 - the outer TransactionScope here will be detected by the new one in senario2
    Senario2();

    transaction.Complete();
  }
}
public void Senario2()
{
  using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
  {
    //your odp.net op here:
    //var cmd = new OracleCommand();
    transaction.Complete();
  }
}
```