# How to get the name of a named transaction in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions

I would like to use the name of a transaction in a trigger in order to write it into a column.

I tried this (in SQL Developer):

```
set transaction name 'hello';
select DBMS_TRANSACTION.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID from dual;
commit;
```

But instead of the name of the transaction I get some kind of random value:

```
transaction NAME succeeded.
SUBSTR(DBMS_TRANSACTION.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID,0,20)
--------------------------------------------------
1.25.19794                                         

committed.
```

How can I get the name of a named transaction?

Answer (score 3):

I just tried something similar, and for the `DBMS_TRANSACTION.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID` I got back the value `9.7.1270`. When I looked up the transaction by name, I found the following:

- `v$transaction.XIDUSN = 9`
- `v$transaction.XIDSLOT = 7`
- `v$transaction.XIDSQN = 1270`

Put them together and you get the `9.7.1270`. So (and note that this could be wrong - the docs I found don't cover this), you *may* be able to get the current transaction name like this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM v$transaction
WHERE xidusn ||'.'|| xidslot ||'.'|| xidsqn = DBMS_TRANSACTION.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID;
```

One fact I could establish: the `v$transaction` row won't show up until you do one of the following:

1. An INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE type of operation, *or*
2. Call `DBMS_TRANSACTION.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID` *on its own* - meaning that just having it in the query above doesn't seem to be enough to populate the `v$transaction` row.

But if I do either of the above, the query works (I've tested it 4 or 5 times now), and since you'll be trying it in a trigger you should be covered by item #2 above.

One final note: `v$transaction` access is fairly restricted, so most users won't be able to see it. Complicating matters, `v$transaction` isn't the actual view; it's a synonym for the view `sys.v_$transaction` (note the underscore before the dollar sign) so that's the name you need to use when granting. And I'm pretty sure you have to be logged in as `SYSDBA` to do the grant - I was able to query `v$transaction` as the `SYSTEM` user but I didn't have sufficient privileges to `GRANT SELECT` to another user.

Comment: How can I argue, that access to the v$ view is harmless?

Comment: *I* think it's harmless, but I don't have compelling proof to back up my position. I'd suggest posting the question on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). Include a quick note about what you're trying to do, and maybe even my query. There are some hard-core Oracle types there who can confirm if it will truly work, and they should be able to tell you if granting access to the view is a good idea. Another option: As the SYSTEM user, create a view on `sys.v_$transaction` (just on the columns you need) then grant access to that view to the users. I tried it here and it worked.

Comment: You tell the security dude, "This is Ed.  He's my manager.  He wants this thing done.  Ed, this is Fred - he's the security guy.  He won't let me do what you want.  Hey, you guys call me when you decide what's what, 'K?  'K.".  Sparking a good management tiff is always fun - AND you're off the hook until they make a decision.  :-)

Comment: On version 18.3, there is no need to have the `DBMS_TRANSACTION.LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID` call on its own (tested it in the select list or in the where condition) but we still need it to "refresh" the `v$transaction` view. It would be interesting to get the doc saying that `v$transaction` might not show every transaction under specific circumstances. If it exists somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for v$transaction.  For example:

```
set serveroutput on
set echo on
set transaction name 'test1_txn';
update my_table set dte = sysdate;
-- this will show the named transaction
select * from v$transaction where name = 'test1_txn';
commit;
-- after commit, won't show
select * from v$transaction where name = 'test1_txn';
```

More detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/transact.htm)

Comment: I get `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` if I try to access that view. As far as I have read I need `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`. I think I will not get this, because it is a system permission.

Comment: its a select priv, pretty harmless imo.  v$ views are owned by SYS (v$transaction is a public synonym to sys.v_$transaction).

Comment: Select in general is not harmless. Selecting passwords is quite harmful. Why do you think it is harmless? I think there must be a reason why I can not access it with my default user.

Comment: if you are required to code triggers or functions that need access about named parameter, then asking for select privs on v$transaction is very normal imo.  If the dbas or management is scared of this select access (for whatever reason), then I'm not sure how you're supposed to do this work.