# Oracle: Is it possible to check the last Session Commit?

Tags: oracle, transactions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell if I have uncommitted work in an Oracle transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506456/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-uncommitted-work-in-an-oracle-transaction)
>   [Oracle: How to find out if there is a transaction pending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending)

I'm using Toad for oracle. Maybe I've forgot to commit the changes I made to the record.
I want to check without giwing another commit.

Is it possible to check the last Session Commit that I give to toad?

Comment: You may need to expand on that a bit. What do you mean, and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is it possible to read the time of the transaction commit?

Comment: @Gik25:For that you need to do some setup,create a materialized view which refreshes on commit,then create a instead of trigger on that,and insert the data on the base table

Comment: @GauravSoni: I need to monitor commit on every table of the database. Maybe you mean a materialized view on a system view?