# Oracle OCI - Determine transaction state, efficiently

Tags: database, oracle, transactions, commit

Is there any way that I can determine a DML was run on current session, and I need to Commit or Rollback the transaction? Efficiently?

**The Problem**

We have a Transaction Manager in our application. It do the Commit/Rollback on each request. But, sometimes we just query some data, and there's no need to Commit/Rollback. We don't want the overhead of frequent commits when there isn't any change.

**Inefficient Solution?**

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509032/324262) suggest to query `dbms_transaction`. But I'm not sure that if it have a less overhead than doing frequent commits. (Overhead both on our application and database.)

Comment: Can't you probe the request SQL and see if it is a DML vs a select?

Comment: It can't be done. Because there maybe some procedure/function call. I can't determine if they executed a DML.